# How can I check if checkbox is checked with Protractor, CucumberJS and Chai?

Tags: javascript, protractor, bdd, chai, cucumberjs

How can I check if checkbox is checked with Protractor, CucumberJS and Chai ?

```
var el = 'myCheckbox';

this.expect(element(by.model(el)).to.have.prop("checked", true));
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`isSelected()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected) would do that:

```
this.expect(element(by.model(el)).isSelected()).to.eventually.be.true;
```

Comment: I tried with this.expect(element(by.model(el)).isSelected()).to.be.true; but it's doesn't work

Comment: I have the same error when I have a syntax error "TypeError: callback.fail is not a function"

Comment: @JérémieChazelle are you using [Chai as Promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised)?

Comment: I use element(by.model(el)), yes chai and chai-as-promised

Comment: @JérémieChazelle okay, I think you need to use `eventually` since this is a promise returned by `isSelected`. Updated, check it out. Thanks.

Comment: I had a problem with isSelected(), and it turned out my element selector was NOT actually grabbing the input checkbox element, so thats something you need to be 100% certain of. (i was using checkboxes underneath a checkbox-list directive)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `this.expect(element(by.model(el)).isSelected()).to.eventually.be(true);`

Answer (score -1):

```
expect(element(by.id("")).isSelected()).toBeFalsy();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: why should be it falsy? Shouldn't it be truthy ?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with the following code and it passed.

**expect(element(by.css("")).get(i).isSelected()).toBeFalsy();**

where,
i corresponds to which checkbox needs to be tested